# create request body and template API GATEWAY CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Please tell me two things:
1. How to configure request body via sdk
2. how to configure template, for pulling pass or query param, converting to json, and then passing it to lambda
This is all in the api gateway and via cdk

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following setup

```js
    const restapi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "myapi", {
            // detail omit
    });

    const helloWorld = new lambda.Function(this, "hello", {
       runtime: lambda.Runtime..PYTHON_3_8,
       handler: 'index.handler',
       code: Code.asset('./index.py')
    })

    restapi.root.addResource("test").addMethod("POST", new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloWorld))
```

and inside the lambda function (in python)

```py
def handler(event, context):
  request_body = event['body']
  parameters = event[queryStringParameters]
```